# Bootstrap Validator to validate on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using bootstrap validator for a basic form however on most occasions all the fields will be already pre-populated. The issue I have with that is that on page load the bootstrap validator currently sets all fields to `data-bv-result="NOT_VALIDATED"` even though all fields are filled correctly so when clicking on submit, the submit form disables itself (and no validation error given) and now I cannot submit the form. If I then remove the `disabled="disabled"` from the submit button, I can then submit the form with no issue, so there is no validation error, just that it doesn't pick up that it already pre-populated.

Is there a way to validate the form on page load so that the `data-bv-result` should say `VALID` instead?

Comment: You can fire `$(form).data('bootstrapValidator').validate()` on document ready

Comment: I get this error is in chrome `Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined`

Comment: You have to change the selector so that it matches your code.

Comment: I did, I placed your code below my validation code and it did the same thing where the submit button became disabled. Thanks for trying

Comment: Documentation [here](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/api/#validate)

Comment: @CarlTaylor1989 have you got your code wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` ?